# Metro bundler user interface not displayed in browser (only json)

Tags: react-native, macos, expo, metro-bundler

I'm a beginner React Native developer. In order to create apps faster, I use Expo 6.0.1 on Mac OS. I've installed it easily (with Yarn) and I can run my apps in browser and emulators. But I have an issue with Metro Bundler.

In the terminal, when I type `w` in order to access the web interface, the browser opens the app itself on port 19006. I should also be able to access the Metro Bundler UI on port 19000. But rather than having this [expected UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fi1k.png) on http://localhost:19000, I have the following kind of json displayed in the browser:

```
{"name":"project","slug":"project","version":"1.0.0","orientation":"portrait","icon":"./assets/icon.png","userInterfaceStyle":"light","splash":{"image":"./assets/splash.png","resizeMode":"contain","backgroundColor":"#ffffff","imageUrl":"http://127.0.0.1:19000/assets/./assets/splash.png"},"updates":{"fallbackToCacheTimeout":0},"assetBundlePatterns":["**/*"],"ios":{"supportsTablet":true},"android":{"adaptiveIcon":{"foregroundImage":"./assets/adaptive-icon.png","backgroundColor":"#FFFFFF","foregroundImageUrl":"http://127.0.0.1:19000/assets/./assets/adaptive-icon.png"}},"web":{"favicon":"./assets/favicon.png"},"_internal":{"isDebug":false,"projectRoot":"/Users/me/Documents/projects/project","dynamicConfigPath":null,"staticConfigPath":"/Users/me/Documents/projects/project/app.json","packageJsonPath":"/Users/me/Documents/projects/project/package.json"},"sdkVersion":"45.0.0","platforms":["ios","android","web"],"developer":{"tool":"expo-cli","projectRoot":"/Users/me/Documents/projects/project"},"packagerOpts":{"scheme":null,"hostType":"lan","lanType":"ip","devClient":false,"dev":true,"minify":false,"urlRandomness":null,"https":false},"mainModuleName":"node_modules/expo/AppEntry","__flipperHack":"React Native packager is running","debuggerHost":"127.0.0.1:19000","logUrl":"http://127.0.0.1:19000/logs","hostUri":"127.0.0.1:19000","bundleUrl":"http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false","iconUrl":"http://127.0.0.1:19000/assets/./assets/icon.png","id":"@anonymous/project-bc40e47a-ee01-4104-9895-13fa07b1c8f4"}
```

I work on Mac OS with expo-cli version 6.0.1 (installed globally with Yarn) and working on Node 16.16.0.

I have already tried :

- to uninstall then reinstall. With node 18.x.y and then node 16.16.0
- delete the metro folder in the node_modules of the project and reinstall everything with Yarn

But no matter what I try, I can't get the UI :(

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just came across your post as have the same issue but have now found out it is now excluded!

*expo-cli@6.0.0 has been released with the web UI removed. The last release to include the web UI is expo-cli@5.5.1.206*

Comment: Hi Steve

Thanks a lot for your answer. I finally came to the same conclusion too. The Expo team decided to sunset this UI because making it more interesting than the terminal would have required too much investment.

Here is the blog post explaining this decision : https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206

I stumbled upon this info thanks to to the Reactiflux community in the #help-react-native channel